# Trying to grasp why internal energy decreases in an isochoric, isentropic process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

So there's this equation:

$dU_{V,S}≤0$

which comes from

$dS≥\frac{dQ}{T}$

$dQ = dU$ since isochoric

$dS≥\frac{dU}{T}$

$TdS≥dU$

$dU≤0$ if $dS=0$

Firstly, are these set of equations valid? If so, how can the internal energy of a system decrease if there is no work done and no change in entropy? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this concept so does anyone have a simple viusalization or example of this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Thermodynamic inequalities**

The inequalities involving $U$, or $H$, or $A$, or $G$ require careful explanation to avoid confusion. First, we have
$$dU = T dS - P d V \tag{1}$$
which is true (we are assuming closed system, $dN=0$ throughout). But then sometimes we also see
$$dU \leq T dS - P d V \tag{2}$$
which, as written, contradicts (1). The proper way to write Eq (2) is
$$
   \Big(\Delta U\Big)_{S,V} \leq 0
$$
and the proper way to read it is:

> *at equilibrium $U$ is at a minimum with respect to partitioning of $S$ and $V$*.

[image]

This is illustrated above: all boxes are in internal equilibrium, but unless parts $A$ and $B$ are in equilibrium *with each other*, $U$ of the combined system is less than the sum of the parts before they were combined, under the constraints $S_A+S_B=\text{const}$, $V_A+V_B=\text{const}$.

By straightforward application of the method of Lagrange multipliers,   minimization of $U_A+U_B$ under these constraints gives
$$
   \frac{\partial U_A}{\partial S_A} 
   =
   \frac{\partial U_B}{\partial S_B}
   = T
\quad\text{and}\quad
   \frac{\partial U_A}{\partial V_A} 
   =
   \frac{\partial U_B}{\partial V_B}
   = -P
$$
which are the familiar equilibrium conditions.

**But why does internal energy *decrease*?**

For the combined system the transition from two parts to one is *isochoric*, therefore, there is no work done. If we did this in an adiabatic experiment by removing the wall between the parts, the entropy of the combined system would increase because the expansion is irreversible. But we are requiring constant entropy, so heat must be *rejected* to the surroundings, and this is why internal energy *decreases*.

Answer (score -1):

If the thermodynamic system is characterized by two parameters, e.g., its temperature and volume, or pressure and volume, or entropy and pressure, etc. as in the case of gasses, then fixing any two will fix everything including its internal energy and when fixed it does not change, of course. But there are more complicated thermodynamic systems involving multiple phases, magnetic, electric chemical, etc, interactions and those are not characterized and controlled by two variables, the remaining variables may spontaneously change within the given constraints and the direction and evolution of these are among the most interesting phenomena in nature.

Answer (score -1):

[The Fundamental thermodynamic identity](http://www.physicsbootcamp.org/The-Fundamental-Thermodynamic-Identity.html) is:
$$
\text{d}U = T\text{d}S - p\text{d}V
$$
*Isentropic process* means no entropy change, that is $\text{d}S=0$. *Isochoric process* means no volume change, that is $\text{d}V=0$. This means that $\text{d}U=0$ as well - the internal energy does not change.